# API not fetching any response even for status 200 in react(Fetch API)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, api, fetch-api

I am integrating an API with my react login form, but I am getting **Failed to load response data: No data found for a resource with given identifier** even for the status code 200.

When I fired the API in postman everything was working fine but when I integrate it with my application it is showing error **index.js:1 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input**

```js
let userLogIn = async function() {
        fetch('http://kishansharma.pythonanywhere.com/login', {
            method: 'POST', 
            mode: 'no-cors', 
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            body: `email=${emailId}&password=${password}`,
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
        console.log('Success:', data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    }
```

I have added the code where I am integrating the API, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you please add in sandbox or codepan so easy to find error on it. Thanks

Comment: @sedhalsoni Here is the sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-forest-y3g9n?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @harsh I got this error also with the 200 OK and null response body - when trying to add a new table api into my app.   The database table field names did not match my client model or my server model.  I had used an underscore in db table, but used a dash in app models. Also, had one property in app models that was missing an attribute.  RowVersion in server model should have [Timestamp] attribute and type byte[], while client model is Uint8Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` usually
comes from invalid json response.
Maybe Postman shows you the raw response as text.
You should check if the response is valid json with no syntax failurs.

Things to try:

- In your `headers` object add the following: `Accept': 'application/json'`
- Is the response realy valid JSON? Sometimes ther is a missing `}`

Comment: I added Accept in the headers, but it makes no difference, The response which I got from the API looks like this:
body: null /
bodyUsed: false/
headers: Headers {}/
ok: false/
redirected: false/
status: 0/
statusText: ""/
type: "opaque"/
url: ""/
[[Prototype]]: Response/